# Function of functions in list

Tags: r

I want to make a list of functions and then make a new function that is the product of those functions. For example, I want to make functions `(x-4i)^2`, for `i=1:50` and then make the product `g=prod_i=1^50 (x-4i)^2`. After doing this I want to take the integral of the product function.

To make the list of the functions, I do:

```
f <- lapply(1:50, function(i){ force(i); function(x) {(x-4i)^2}})
```

Then I have a list of all functions I want. My problem is how to make the product as a function? I tried many ways but it always leads to "infinite recursion". Could someone please help me?

Comment: this is most definitely not html. what is this?

Comment: @Doorknob I think it's `r`. `lapply` is a function available in `r`.

Comment: If you want the right people to find and answer this question, tag it properly.

Comment: Html? I don't see any here. Can u add relevant tags please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all `x-4i` has a special meaning: it becomes a complex number. I suspect you want to use `x-4*i`. So,

```
f <- lapply(1:50, function(i){ force(i); function(x) {(x-4*i)^2}})
```

To get the product function of these functions you need to evaluate them at the point before multiplying:

```
fprod <- function(x) prod(sapply(f,function(y) y(x)))
fprod(0)
[1] 1.486445e+189
fprod(1)
[1] 1.394667e+188
```

To integrate, you will need to use a `Vectorize`d function:

```
integrate(Vectorize(fprod),0,10)
6.328303e+188 with absolute error < 2.1e+181
```

But note that such large numbers may have accuracy issues.